# Getting translated string using reflection and Resource Manager

Tags: c#, reflection, localization

I wrote the following code to get the translated string from Resource Manager. The method `GetTranslatedString` is called more than 50 times in my project.

```
  public static string GetTranslatedString(string input, string culture)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;
        string retInput = input;
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Globalization.XYZ", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var entry = rm.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, true)
            .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key.ToString().Equals(input, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (entry.Value == null) return retInput;
        return entry.Value.ToString();

    }
```

But I feel it's not perfect code because the `ResourceManager` class gets new instances many times and since I'm calling `GetTranslatedString` many times I am sure it will impact on performance.

Second major problem is, I am using reflection inside this code. and it's a costly operation.

It would helpful if I could get review on this.

Comment: updated the post, if there is no translation I am returning the input back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public static string GetTranslatedString(string input, string culture)
> {
>     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;
>     string retInput = input;
>     CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
>     ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Tesla.TSS.Globalization.SchedulingSystem", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
>
>     var entry = rm.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, true)
>         .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
>         .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Key.ToString().Equals(input, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
>     if (entry.Value == null) return retInput;
>     return entry.Value.ToString();
>
> }
> ```

Because the resources of your application won't change during runtime, the easiest way would be to once get the whole items and store them in a dictionary. Then your application can use the dictionary to retrieve the translated strings.

I would like to suggest to make this a little bit more flexible, so you could use it in other projects too.

At first the method which will retrieve the `Dictionary<string,string>` from the `ResourceManager`

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetTranslations(CultureInfo cultureInfo, string baseName, Assembly assembly)
{
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(baseName, assembly);

    using (ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(cultureInfo, true, true))
    {
        return rs.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
                 .ToDictionary(r => r.Key.ToString(),
                      r => r.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

as you can see, this can be called independent from your current project.

Now let us add an overloaded method which takes the culture as a string like so

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetTranslations(string culture, string baseName, Assembly assembly)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
    return GetTranslations(cultureInfo, baseName, assembly);
}
```

In your project you can call it now like

```
Dictionary<string,string> translations = GetTranslations(culture, "Tesla.TSS.Globalization.SchedulingSystem", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

and you could query this to get the translated strings.

You could have a method `ChangeLanguage(string culture)` like so

```
private string currentCultureName = "en-Us";
private void ChangeLanguage(string culture)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(culture)) 
    {
        currentCultureName = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        currentCultureName = culture;
    }

    translations = GetTranslations(culture, "Tesla.TSS.Globalization.SchedulingSystem", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

to change the current dictionary.

Your former `GetTranslatedString()` method should then live as a class method (not static) inside your project and should look like so

```
public string GetTranslatedString(string input, string culture)
{

    if (input == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("input"); }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) { return input; }

    if (currentCultureName != culture)
    {
        ChangeLanguage(culture);
    }

    string translation;
    if (translations.TryGetValue(input, out translation))
    {
        return translation;
    }

    return input;
}
```

As you can see I have change quite a few things like

- adding braces `{}` although they are optional for single line `if` statements, but they will make the code less error prone.
- for a passed in `input` which is `null` this will throw an `ArgumentNullException` which is much better than just returning the `null`.
- for the passed in `culture` I didn't add a `null` check, because if the `ChangeLanguage()` method will be called with a `null` value the name of the `CurrentUICulture` will be used.

Comment: Thank you. I am implementing it. sounds good. keep you posted

Comment: I am just doing sample project for my school academic. your way of reviewing helped a lot, we all students learned a lot in this answer. Thank you with respect Heslacher.